# Why is Postfix trying to connect to other machines SMTP port 25?

Tags: postfix, smtp

I get these errors:

```
Jul  5 11:09:25 relay postfix/smtp[3084]: connect to ab.xyz.com[10.41.0.101]:25: Connection refused
Jul  5 11:09:25 relay postfix/smtp[3087]: connect to ab.xyz.com[10.41.0.247]:25: Connection refused
Jul  5 11:09:25 relay postfix/smtp[3088]: connect to ab.xyz.com[10.41.0.101]:25: Connection refused
Jul  5 11:09:25 relay postfix/smtp[3084]: connect to ab.xyz.com[10.41.0.247]:25: Connection refused
Jul  5 11:09:25 relay postfix/smtp[3087]: connect to ab.xyz.com[10.41.0.110]:25: Connection refused
Jul  5 11:09:25 relay postfix/smtp[3088]: connect to ab.xyz.com[10.41.0.110]:25: Connection refused
Jul  5 11:09:25 relay postfix/smtp[3084]: connect to ab.xyz.com[10.41.0.102]:25: Connection refused
Jul  5 11:09:30 relay postfix/smtp[3085]: connect to ab.xyz.com[10.41.0.102]:25: Connection refused
Jul  5 11:09:30 relay postfix/smtp[3086]: connect to ab.xyz.com[10.41.0.247]:25: Connection refused
Jul  5 11:09:30 relay postfix/smtp[3086]: connect to ab.xyz.com[10.41.0.102]:25: Connection refused
Jul  5 11:09:55 relay postfix/smtp[3087]: connect to ab.xyz.com[10.40.40.130]:25: Connection timed out
Jul  5 11:09:55 relay postfix/smtp[3084]: connect to ab.xyz.com[10.40.40.130]:25: Connection timed out
Jul  5 11:09:55 relay postfix/smtp[3088]: connect to ab.xyz.com[10.40.40.130]:25: Connection timed out
Jul  5 11:09:55 relay postfix/smtp[3087]: connect to ab.xyz.com[10.41.0.135]:25: Connection refused
Jul  5 11:09:55 relay postfix/smtp[3084]: connect to ab.xyz.com[10.41.0.110]:25: Connection refused
Jul  5 11:09:55 relay postfix/smtp[3088]: connect to ab.xyz.com[10.41.0.247]:25: Connection refused
```

Is this a DNS thing, doubtful as I've changed from our local DNS to Google's..still Postfix will occasionally try and connect to ab.xyz.com from a variety of addresses that may or may not have port 25 open and act as mail servers to begin with.

**Why is Postfix attempting to connect to other machines as seen in the log?**

- Mail is being sent properly, other than that, it appears all is good.

Occasionally I'll also see:

> relay postfix/error[3090]: 3F1AB42132: to=,
>   relay=none, delay=32754, delays=32724/30/0/0, dsn=4.4.1,
>   status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to
>   ab.xyz.com[10.41.0.102]:25: Connection refused)

I have Postfix setup with very little restrictions:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 10.0.0.0/8
```

only. Like I said it appears all mail is getting passed through, but I hate seeing errors and it is confusing me as to why it would be attempting to connect to other machines as seen in the log.

Some Output of `cat /var/log/mail.log|grep 3F1AB42132`

> Jul  5 02:04:01 relay postfix/smtpd[1653]: 3F1AB42132:
>   client=unknown[10.41.0.109]
>
> Jul  5 02:04:01 relay postfix/cleanup[1655]: 3F1AB42132:
>   message-id=
>
> Jul  5 02:04:01 relay postfix/qmgr[1588]: 3F1AB42132:
>   from=, size=3404, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Jul  5 02:04:31 relay postfix/smtp[1634]: 3F1AB42132:
>   to=, relay=none, delay=30,
>   delays=0.02/0/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to
>   ab.xyz.com[10.41.0.110]:25: Connection refused)
>
> Jul  5 02:13:58 relay postfix/qmgr[1588]: 3F1AB42132:
>   from=, size=3404, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Jul  5 02:14:28 relay postfix/smtp[1681]: 3F1AB42132:
>   to=, relay=none, delay=628,
>   delays=598/0.01/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to
>   ab.xyz.com[10.41.0.247]:25: Connection refused)
>
> Jul  5 02:28:58 relay postfix/qmgr[1588]: 3F1AB42132:
>   from=, size=3404, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Jul  5 02:29:28 relay postfix/smtp[1684]: 3F1AB42132:
>   to=, relay=none, delay=1527,
>   delays=1497/0/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to
>   ab.xyz.com[10.41.0.135]:25: Connection refused)
>
> Jul  5 02:58:58 relay postfix/qmgr[1588]: 3F1AB42132:
>   from=, size=3404, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Jul  5 02:59:28 relay postfix/smtp[1739]: 3F1AB42132:
>   to=, relay=none, delay=3327,
>   delays=3297/0/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to
>   ab.xyz.com[10.40.40.130]:25: Connection timed out)
>
> Jul  5 03:58:58 relay postfix/qmgr[1588]: 3F1AB42132:
>   from=, size=3404, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Jul  5 03:59:28 relay postfix/smtp[1839]: 3F1AB42132:
>   to=, relay=none, delay=6928,
>   delays=6897/0.03/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to
>   ab.xyz.com[10.41.0.101]:25: Connection refused)
>
> Jul  5 04:11:03 relay postfix/qmgr[2039]: 3F1AB42132:
>   from=, size=3404, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Jul  5 04:11:33 relay postfix/error[2093]: 3F1AB42132:
>   to=, relay=none, delay=7653,
>   delays=7622/30/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily
>   suspended: connect to ab.xyz.com[10.41.0.101]:25: Connection refused)
>
> Jul  5 05:21:03 relay postfix/qmgr[2039]: 3F1AB42132:
>   from=, size=3404, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Jul  5 05:21:33 relay postfix/error[2217]: 3F1AB42132:
>   to=, relay=none, delay=11853,
>   delays=11822/30/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily
>   suspended: connect to ab.xyz.com[10.41.0.101]:25: Connection refused)
>
> Jul  5 06:29:25 relay postfix/qmgr[2420]: 3F1AB42132:
>   from=, size=3404, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Jul  5 06:29:55 relay postfix/error[2428]: 3F1AB42132:
>   to=, relay=none, delay=15954,
>   delays=15924/30/0/0.08, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery
>   temporarily suspended: connect to ab.xyz.com[10.41.0.101]:25:
>   Connection refused)
>
> Jul  5 07:39:24 relay postfix/qmgr[2885]: 3F1AB42132:
>   from=, size=3404, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Jul  5 07:39:54 relay postfix/error[2936]: 3F1AB42132:
>   to=, relay=none, delay=20153,
>   delays=20123/30/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily
>   suspended: connect to ab.xyz.com[10.40.40.130]:25: Connection timed
>   out)

Comment: can you paste more logs - "cat /var/log/mail.log|grep 3F1AB42132" can be helpful

Comment: pQd's command will get you the `To:` and `From:` addresses which will probably be enough to answer your question.

Comment: Maybe you have an entry in /etc/hosts which overwrite the DNS resolve ? The think is from what I can see that some of the local clients (10.41.0.109) is trying to send some email to ab.xyz.com and your smtp servers resolve that IP to 10.41.0.101. What is the output of `nslookup ab.xyz.com` on your smtp server ? Btw MX records for ab.xyz.com points to gmail.

Comment: @golja exactly right! So I will have to clean up DNS. Thanks for pointing that out...nslokup resolves 10.41.0.109

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most likely they are wrong email addresses or your DNS resolution is failing.

Postfix will try to connect to the SMTP server according to the MX record of the `ab.xyz.com` domain to deliver the email, but if Postfix cannot find a MX record, it will attempt to deliver to the IP of the A record. (That's the expected behavior).

But if the email address domain is wrong (miss-typed, for example) the domain may exist but maybe does not have a MX record and the IP from the A record is a host without a SMTP server.

As an example, some people around here type `myaddress@hotmail.com.mx` (the correct address is `myaddress@hotmail.com`), however the `hotmail.com.mx` domain indeed exists but does not have an MX record, so Postfix tries, and tries, and tries to deliver to an `A` record host who will never answer at port 25, causing log entries like:

```
Jul  5 17:03:37 www postfix/smtp[3149]: 6608A108FD2: to=<xyz@hotmail.com.mx>, relay=none, delay=197971, delays=197971/0.02/0.18/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to hotmail.com.mx[200.94.181.9]:25: Connection refused)
```

Comment: Great explanation, and that clarifies things for me too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Additional things to check for when you are seeing logs like this are,

myhostname and mydestination need to be set correctly in  /etc/postfix/main.cf